# How to use Switch case In the Java

Tags: java

I am using Neatbeans 7.0 for Java programming. I have written a Switch case for selection of the program.

```
switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                //stmt
            }
            default:
            {
                //stmt
                return;
            }
        }
```

I am getting compile time error at `switch(menu)`

```
The Error is "strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

(Alt-Enter shows hints)" Can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `menu` is a string type, though it doesn't really match your case statements. Allowing the use of strings in `switch` statements was added in Java 7.

You can either switch to Java 7 and fix the `case` so that it checks against a string rather that the integral `1`, or convert `menu` to an integer and check that, such as with `Integer.ParseInt()`, something like:

```
String menu = "1";
int menuint;
try {
    menuint = Integer.ParseInt (menu);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    menuint = -1;
}
switch (menuint) {
   :
```

Comment: Thanks A lot for your help. As I understand We cannot use String Inside the Switch case hence we have to first convert that string to Integer And then use that Integer Inside the Switch case.

Answer (score 4):

String cases in switch statements are supported in [Java SE 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/), but not in previous versions of Java. You need to compile with Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Type of menu is String in your code. If you've JDK 1.6 then switch expression type should be   int or char.

You need to change [project properties](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html) :

1. Source : Source/Binary format : JDK7
2. Libraries : JDK1.7

Comment: based on the case in this example, probably int

Answer (score 1):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types.

String is unsupported until Java-6. Java 7 supports String object in switch-case.

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression.

Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
case "1":
```

....